Python - OpenCV Videocapture stuck
I have a esp32cam with a stream on a webserver. When I try to open the stream with opencv it gets stuck
import cv2
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

raw_stream = cv2.VideoCapture()
raw_stream.open("http://eps32cam-rsr.local:81/stream") #it cant get past this line

while raw_stream.isOpened():
    try:
        success, image = raw_stream.read()
        if success:
            image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            img = Image.fromarray(image)
            pic = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
            label_stream = tk.Label(window, image=pic)
            label_stream.image = pic
            label_stream.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.7, anchor="center", height=240, width=320)
        else:
            break

    except:
        pass

When I look in the serial of the esp32 i can see that python gets the stream, but gets stuck and doesn't process it.
I tried different IP addresses: no success
I tried reinstalling opencv multiple times
One week ago it worked, but now not anymore. I dont know what changed.

You are missing parameter. The index should be zero cv2.VideoCapture(0)

no... this is a valid way to instantiate a VideoCapture. -- [mre] required. you lack the tk import, and probably a lot more. MRE also implies that you need to either provide such a video stream for others to reproduce the issue, or present instructions/code so anyone can create it locally, or you need to rip it out and replace it in a way that still causes the issue.
